# Trying to display a "map" of allocated memory in a simulated OS memory manager

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, mkfifo

Multiple clients are sending the name of their job and their memory request to the server. The server is acting as a memory manager and allocating memory for as many clients as possible using paging as its memory allocation scheme. I am using FIFO's for client-server communication.

The problem I am having is after all clients have been processed, I would like to display a map of the allocated memory on the server-side. In other words, I would like to show *what* **frames** have been allocated to *what* **client**.

Below is part of my server application. I have also attached some output that may help understand the problem. Everything works as expected until the end of the program (where it prints out the frames assigned to each client; the last **for** loop on ***server.c***). The clientsAllocation array is the array that holds each client's private FIFO name. I was trying to assign the index of the allocated frame (in allocatedFrames array) to be the client's privateFIFOName. I'm not sure why this isn't working. Thank you in advance for any help.

*Any answer should be portable. I have to be able to run this code on a UNIX machine using the cygwin-gcc compiler. I am testing the code on Windows because it is my primary machine. I connect to a UNIX machine at my University using PuTTY every couple of code changes and make sure the code runs on there too.*

***server.c***

```
...//include statements

#define FRAMESIZE 256
#define MAX_LENGTH_FIFO_NAME 16
#define MAX_LENGTH_JOB_NAME 32
#define MAX_LENGTH_MESSAGE 256

int main(void)
{
    int numOfClients = 0; //total number of clients this server will process
    int totalNumOfFrames = 0; //total number of frames in memory
    int frames = 0; //copy of numOfFrames used to allocate frames for client

    //Struct to recieve from client
    struct
    {
        char jobName[MAX_LENGTH_JOB_NAME];
        char privateFIFOName[MAX_LENGTH_FIFO_NAME];
        int memoryRequest;
    }input;

    //Struct to send to client containing the calculated frames and the fragmentation
    struct
    {
        char message[MAX_LENGTH_MESSAGE];
        int fragmentation;
        int totalNumOfFrames;
        int frameNumbers[totalNumOfFrames];
    }output;

    ... //getting input from user and doing error checking

    int allocatedFrames[totalNumOfFrames]; //an array of "flags" that will keep track whether a frame is allocated or not
    char* clientsAllocation[totalNumOfFrames]; //an array to keep track of what frames are allocated to what client

    memset(allocatedFrames, 0, sizeof(allocatedFrames)); //make sure all values in the array are set to 0 to prevent random values
    memset(clientsAllocation, 0, sizeof(clientsAllocation));

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (i; i < numOfClients; i++)
    {
        if (input.memoryRequest >= FRAMESIZE && input.memoryRequest <= memoryLeft)
        {
            ...
            frames = 0;

            if (framesLeft >= numOfFrames)
            {
                j = 0;
                while (frames < numOfFrames)
                {
                    for (j; j < totalNumOfFrames; j++)
                    {
                        if (allocatedFrames[j] == 0) //if the value at j is 0, then this is an empty frame and can be allocated
                        {
                            allocatedFrames[j] = 1; //switch the value to 1 in both arrays
                            output.frameNumbers[j] = 1;
                            clientsAllocation[j] = input.privateFIFOName; //keep track of what frames this client was allocated
                            printf("%d: %s\n", j, clientsAllocation[j]);
                            printf("SERVER:> Frame Allocated: %d\n", j);
                            break; //breaks out of this 'for' loop which should only be run as many times as there are frames to be allocated
                        }
                    }
                    frames++; //increment the temporary frames variable to keep track of how many times to run the for loop
                }

                ... //calculations on framesLeft and memoryLeft
            }
            //if it is not a valid request, (i.e. requesting more frames than are available)
            else
            {
                ... //some error printing
            }
        }
        else if (...)... //range checking but the code is very similar to above
    }

    i = 0;
    for (i; i < totalNumOfFrames; i++)
    {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, clientsAllocation[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: That's a *lot* of mostly irrelevant code. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Ethan, there is a special hell for programmers who write functions more than 20 lines long.  You seem to be in it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thanks for tips. I have edited my question and taken out a lot of irrelevant code. I hope it is easier to understand what the problem I'm having is.

Comment: @jwdonahue, the length of a function is completely opinion based. I recognize that main is a function and my main is quite long. However, I am just starting out in C and am learning as I go through my Operating Systems class. So, I would appreciate helpful criticism. Saying I belong in programmer hell is not helpful at all.

Comment: @Ethan, statistics show that most software bugs appear in functions longer than 10 lines. Many companies have soft/hard limits on function length due to expensive lessons learned. Keep that in mind the next time you fail to find your own bugs in your excessively long functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always assigning the same buffers address to the currently used entry of your array of client names.

```
clientsAllocation[j] = input.privateFIFOName;
```

You do so by giving the name/identifier of the array of char in your input struct.
It is treated as a pointer to char and assigned to all used entries inside `clientsAllocation`.

So at the end, when printing, all the pointers refer to the same array of `char`
and you get a list of identical names, being the last one written to the buffer.

To avoid that, you could malloc() some memory for each name and fill it with the current name via string copying.

Of course, you should free those allocated memories at some point.
For the simple demo program, freeing after printing seems appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I realized what was going on after I read the chapter on pointers and manipulating strings in my C textbook. I appreciate the help and pointing me in the right direction! :)